# Manage pages displayed in Progressive Web Apps ( PWA )

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am new to PWA and was just going through some readups. We have public website and in the website we provide login for users to manage their account. By going with PWA, I understand that users can save the website on the mobile homepage  as an icon. My question is that , when user click on my PWA icon , can we load the login page for the users so that they can only manage account with PWA instead of loading entire website.

Answer (score 2):

The [Web App Manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/) allows you to control how your app appears and how it's launched. You can specify home screen icons, the page to load when the app is launched, screen orientation, and even whether or not to show the browser chrome.

> The [web app manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) is a simple JSON file that gives you, the developer, the ability to control how your app appears to the user in areas where they would expect to see apps (for example, a mobile device's home screen), direct what the user can launch, and define its appearance at launch.

You can define how your app is launched, add a query string parameter to the `start_url` that indicates how it was launched.

```
"start_url": "/?utm_source=homescreen"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, within your web app manifest file you can set a JSON property called `"start_url"`.

There's further information here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/#set_a_start_url